# How can I make an iPhone app that responds to the OnRing event?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to write a iPhone application, it needs to react to the `onRing` event (or whenever someone calls, regardless of their ring/vibrate settings).

Is this possible? Would my application have to be running all the time or can it just run during a ring? (it is a light application, not sure how long it will take to load up though).

I basically want to react to a ring, and then determine whether to ring or vibrate.

Comment: It can't be done - at least not "legally".

Comment: This is undoubtably possible, however this app would not be accepted into the App Store by Apple ( no daemon apps and you must use only published APIs ).

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible unless you have a jailbroken phone.

Answer (score 1):

If your application is currently running when the call comes in, you'll receive the notification UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification indicating that the app will go offscreen and be replaced by the call screen.

I think that's the only way you can do it without a jailbroken phone, though.

Comment: Even then, all you get is a notification, so that you can save the state of your app or something, you can't stop it, modify it or do anything else with it.